# Is "supply" the inverse of "apply"?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

We can say "The add function is applied to values 1 and 2". Can we say equivalently "The values 1 and 2 are supplied to the add function"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's dangerous to generalize that *supply* is the inverse (or opposite) of *apply*. It might sound that way when speaking of functions, or possibly other things, but there are many nuances to the usage of *supply* and *apply* that would make most reversals sound strange or contrived.

In fact, there would be many cases where they are used nearly as *synonyms* not reversals.

> The machine applies a magnetic field.

and

> The machine supplies a magnetic field.

Mind you,

> A magnetic field is supplied by the machine.

or

> A magnetic field is applied by the machine.

Are perfectly correct. So what's going on here? How can they be near synonyms and inverse at the same time? I think *supply/apply* are not nearly the same inverse pair as, say, *input/output*. It's not that cut and dried.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can.

Similarly we can say

> The machine is applied to flour and
>   sugar to make cake

or

> Flour and sugar is supplied to the
>   machine to make cake

though this sounds a little contrived.

*Supply* is the inverse of *apply* only in certain contexts.

Comment: are there similarities for other word pairs too? Like "submit" vs "admit" or something (I understand that this one isn't such a pair :))?

Comment: I don't agree. "The machine is applied to flour and sugar to make cake" sounds strange and contrived.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, your syntax is correct. You apply a function to one or more parameters, and you supply one or more parameters to a function.